# Finding multiple variables within a single column on data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Sorry if this isn't laid out correctly, still in very early stages of R and these forums!

I have an extremely large, global dataset split into countries using the ISO country code however I am only after the European countries.

I can successfully highlight one variable from the dataset

```
test1[country_code=="BE",]
```

How can I extract all the European codes? I have tried & and | but unsuccessfully.

Comment: This has really not much to do with *data.table* R package.. I suggest learning base R first, and then going through the [HTML vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started)

Comment: If you're looking to identify which ISO codes correspond to European countries, you might ask on a specialized forum or maybe http://opendata.stackexchange.com/tour (It's not clear to me what you're asking.)

Answer (score 5):

try defining a list of Euro countries, then make use of %in%

```
euro_codes <- c('BE', 'DE', ...)
test1[ country_code %in% euro_codes, ]
```

Comment: Just `%in%` will suffice, the `which(...)` isn't needed.

Comment: Also, `%chin%` could be used (in case `country_code` is character). Or binary join as in `setkey(test1, country_code)[.(country_codes)]`

Comment: I've grown so accustomed to using which() all the time! please let me know if my edit is incorrect...

Answer (score 1):

This creates a new data table (single column) with the list of all unique country codes :

```
country.codes <- as.data.table(unique(test1[,country_code]))
```

You can easily determine the European country codes from the newly extracted small list of country codes.